# No module named pycurl

Tags: php, python

I am trying to convert multiple IP 2 DOMAINS using SSH root server. I am using these cmds `cd opd +ls + chmod +x * + python url.py 50`  but I get the error below when I run this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "url.py", line 1, in <module>
import pycurl
ImportError: No module named pycurl
```

What is missing here? I am stuck here, please help or advise.

Comment: `pycurl` is not a built-in standard module/library, so you'll need to download and install it in order to be able to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the [`pycurl`](http://pycurl.io/) module. This is typically accomplished with

```
pip install pycurl
```

Comment: Thank you friend,now i know where to download pycurl from.My question is,where am i suppose to install the pycurl,is it on my SSH root Server cmd terminal or where,if you can give me steps and guide to installing pycurl,i would greatly appreciate that brother...Thanks.

Comment: I tried to install pycurl with the cmd " pip install pycurl" on Python terminal consile on my computer and this was the result that i got  ===  Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install pycurl
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pycurl
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: I also try to instal pycurl on the root SSH server via putty with this cmd "pip install pycurl" and got this error report===  
Last login: Sat May 26 00:24:18 2018 from 45.222.194.34
admin@Sinoserver:~$ pip install pycurl
-sh: pip: command not found
admin@Sinoserver:~$ login as: admin

Comment: Where exactly am i suppose to install pycurl to avoid this error when i try to run this cmd ls + chmod +x * + python url.py 50 to convert IP's to Domains..Please help me..Anybody. Pls.

Comment: The command is not made to be run from the Python terminal, the second option was correct. It looks like pip isn't installed on your system - I suggest following these instructions to install it: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Thank you James,please can u tell me how to contact you privately? maybe email or by sms

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not going to give out my contact details. I'm sorry I can't be more help in this limited format :(

Answer (score 0):

install not in the python shell but in your virtual environment: just your normal terminal